# How to change bootstrap modal size from a link attribute with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder if it's possible to change the bootstrap modal size by reading an attribute from a link. For example, bootstrap modal will change from a normal size into a larger size when an attribute is declared.

`<a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xModal" modal-size="large">xModal</a>`

So the jquery will listen for a click and fire up the modal like

```
        if($('a[attr='modal-size']') === "large"){
            $('#xModal').modal('show'); 
            $(".modal-dialog").html("modal-lg");
          }
```

Can I succeed the code by this idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can listen `show.bs.modal` event and change the width with you `data-modal-width` value like so:

**HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#xModal" data-modal-width="900">xModal</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('#xModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);  // Button that triggered the modal
    var modal = $(this);

    modal.css('width', button.data('modal-width') + 'px');
});
```

Comment: It's looking good Bluety, but it's gives me another problem. I use the modal `#xModal` as a dynamic modal - sending url via `href`. So is it possible to toggle the modal width only when `data-modal-width` is detected?

Comment: Yes you can just replace `$('#xModal')` by `$('[data-modal-with]')`. But be careful, this selector his much less efficient. You can also add a specific class: `<a class="modal-custom-width" data-toggle="modal" >xModal</a>` and target with `$('.modal-custom-width')`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not call the modal from this data attributes for the simple reason that you just described, you can´t really control what is happening before the modal toogles.
Better is using an onclick event or listen to the click on the 
than you could do something like:

```
<a  onclick="handleModal()" modal-size="large">xModal</a>

handleModal(){
if($('a[attr='modal-size']') === "large"){
            $('#xModal').modal('show'); 
            $(".modal-dialog").html("modal-lg");
          }
}
```

or:

```
 <a  id="x1" modal-size="large">xModal</a>

 $(function(){
  $('#x1').onclick(function(){
   if($('a[attr='modal-size']') === "large"){
                $('#xModal').modal('show'); 
                $(".modal-dialog").html("modal-lg");
   } 
 })
})
```

Comment: Joh, it's not work. It freeze my page with no reason :(

Comment: does the page freeze at both options?